# Enumerate starting at equation number

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, automation

The following MWE contains proofs of equations numbered (2) through (4). I structure the proofs using an `enumerate` environment, so that the proof of equation (2) is labeled with `2.`, the proof of (3) with `3.`, and (4) with `4.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

An equation before the proof:
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2.
\end{equation}

%I might want another equation here:
%\begin{equation}
%a^2 + b^2 = c^2
%\end{equation}

Here is a list of equations we want to prove:
\begin{align}
F &= ma \label{eq:newton} \\
\tau &= r \times F \label{eq:torque} \\
I &= \frac{3}{17} MR^2. \label{eq:inertia}
\end{align}

We will prove the equations in order:
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
\item The first equation is trivial.
\item The second equation follows easily.
\item The third is left as an exercise to the reader.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If I were to add another equation before the list of equations to be proved, though, the numbering might change, so that I am now proving equations (3) through (5) for instance. I would like the numbering in the `enumerate` environment to change automatically. However, using

```
\setcounter{enumi}{\ref{eq:newton}}
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
```

does not work.

How can I make the `enumerate` environment automatically start its numbering at the number of a particular equation?

Comment: This can't work, since `\ref` isn't expandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of juggling with `\addtocounter{enumi}` etc it's better to use `enumitem` and it's `start=...` option.

The `\getrefnumber{...}` macro from `refcount` provides an aid to get the real 'number' of an reference -- `\ref` isn't expandable and will fail here.

Please note: `\getrefnumber{...}` will yield anything as `equation` number here, i.e. something `1.A.5` would be possible too -- `start=...` will fail then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

An equation before the proof:
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2.
\end{equation}

%I might want another equation here:
%\begin{equation}
%a^2 + b^2 = c^2
%\end{equation}

Here is a list of equations we want to prove:
\begin{align}
F &= ma \label{eq:newton} \\
\tau &= r \times F \label{eq:torque} \\
I &= \frac{3}{17} MR^2. \label{eq:inertia}
\end{align}

We will prove the equations in order:
\begin{enumerate}[start=\getrefnumber{eq:newton}]
\item The first equation is trivial.
\item The second equation follows easily.
\item The third is left as an exercise to the reader.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]